# ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

We use a small sql function which splits string by some delimiter and returns these values in a table.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [shark].[SplitStrings]
(
   @List      VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN ( SELECT [Item], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [Id] FROM
      ( SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
        FROM ( SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>'
        + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
          ) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i) ) AS y
      WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
  );
```

The question is if this can change the order of the elements from the string?

Ex.

```
 SELECT * FROM [shark].[SplitStrings] ('1,2,3,4,5', ',')
```

Can this return

```
1
5
3
4
2
```

instead of

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

?

MORE INFORMATION:
After months of normal working, we found a bug in one of our components and the only source which we could find and which could cause this bug is the mentioned procedure. It somehow changed the order of the string array which contained 65 000 elements (the total length of the string with delimiters was 65 000 * 11). We tried to reproduce the same error on the same sql server but without any luck. Your comments and answers made this sproc more guilty.

Comment: All that that `ORDER BY` clause is there for is to define what `ROW_NUMBER()` values are assigned to rows. But since all rows are being given the same value within that clause, the row numbers assigned are in no way guaranteed. And none of this guarantees to affect *the order in which results are returned*.

Comment: I agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever. The lack of a logical order could result in any order. I had a query that had returned data for years in the order that I wanted and after a SQL Server upgrade, it started providing it in a different order because there was no explicit order by. We've made our functions that are similar loop to provide accurate row numbering; not efficient, but correct.

Comment: XQuery *does* process elements in order, so if you wanted to make this more robust, implement a counter in there (XQuery has native node counting functions as well, but SQL Server does not implement them). The XML nodes do have an order. The `ROW_NUMBER()` does not. In practice, I don't know if you could ever observe the optimizer stepping out of turn here -- if it's possible, then probably for a large set, if a parallel plan is picked, but your strings are probably too small to ever trigger that.

Comment: You might take a peek at this splitter. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ It is super fast and provides the ordinal position of each element. It does have a limitation of varchar(8000) for input though and you have varchar(max) so that could be a potential issue.

Answer (score 1):

In general a select statement will always return a unsorted resultset. So the general answer to you question is: Yes, your select statement can return any order of elements. This would confirm to the SQL-standard. (And better never trust to anything else.)

But: You put an implicit order within your function. This order is produced by the order of the -elements within the XML-Fragment. This XML is processed in just the order you constructed the string that is converted to XML. This is used as the right side of your cross apply (you can't use and don't need any order by here). So the answer to your question is: No, your select statement will always return the given order of elements.

Comment: I know that XML is processed in order of the elements but I have never read anything that explicitly states the data will be returned in that order. If the order of the data is important than an explicit order by is the only safe way to go. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: This is not correct, for the reason Sean specifies. In particular, `CROSS APPLY` implies no order. *Nothing* in T-SQL implies order except `ORDER BY`, but then, obviously, not `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` as is used here, as that's still nondeterministic. Even if the statement was wrapped again with an `ORDER BY Id`, this would ultimately guarantee nothing because the inner rowset has a nondeterministic order (and nothing can *give* it a deterministic order). In *practice*, a query like this will *almost certainly* have in-order row processing, but there's no *guarantee*.

Comment: @Jeroen: I think we all agree that there is no guarantee in SQL for a given order as long as there is no explicit 'order by'. In the given SQL there is an order within the XML-elements. Within XML elements do have an order by definition (not so with XML-attributes). So processing this XML elements has to keep that order unless you would miss some information (bwt. there is no way to declare an order in procession  XML-nodes as it is declared 'by structure').

Comment: Yes, the XML elements are ordered, but that doesn't *help*. You will get back the same XML structure in the inner query every time, but once those elements are shredded back to rows using the `CROSS APPLY`, all bets are off again, and the `ROW_NUMBER()` is applied after that step. The only way to exploit the XML ordering is to actually add the row number to the XML itself.

Comment: Are you sure about this: The only way [within MS-SQL-Server] to exploit the XML ordering is to add the row number to the XML itself? Do you have any source for that information (MSDN...)?

Comment: Given *any rowset*, whether it is the product of an XML operation or not, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` is *not* guaranteed to give you row numbers in any particular order. Do you agree on that, at least? The conclusion basically follows from there.

Comment: There is no discussion about that (row_number). The question is whether 'cross apply' on a node-set would inherit the order defined by the ordering of the XML or would only have an order if there is an explicite 'order by' at that part of the statement (what cannot be defined in this case).

Comment: I'm going to go with "no". Neither `nodes()` nor `CROSS APPLY` are documented to preserve or output order in any way. I can't prove a negative in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Some more info, that does not fit in the comments:

The minimal statement for that question would be something like

```
SELECT x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Item
FROM 
   (SELECT CONVERT(XML, '<i>1</i><i>2</i>') as [XML]) AS a 
CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i);
```

The question reduced to this: Might the result be in this order?

```
2
1
```

The execution plan of this query looks like this:

```
|--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1011]=[Expr1010]))
   |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Expr1000], XML Reader with XPath filter.[id]))
        |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Expr1000]))
        |    |--Constant Scan(VALUES:((CONVERT(xml,'<i>1</i><i>2</i>',0))))
        |    |--Filter(WHERE:(STARTUP EXPR([Expr1000] IS NOT NULL)))
        |         |--Table-valued function
        |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1010]=MIN(CASE WHEN [Expr1000] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CASE WHEN datalength(XML Reader with XPath filter.[value])>=(128) THEN CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(100),XML Reader with XPath filter.[lvalue],0) ELSE CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(100),XML Reader with XPath filter.[value],0) END END)))
             |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
                  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1009]=0x58))
                       |--Filter(WHERE:(XML Reader with XPath filter.[id]=getancestor(XML Reader with XPath filter.[id],(1))))
                            |--Table-valued function
```

Maybe there is a reason for ordering of the elements within the nested loop with data coming from the XML Reader, but this is not sure and no documentation about this could be found.

And even no documentation could be found on the question: How to properly keep the ordering without changing the XML structure (i.e. adding a sortkey within the XML)?